# 2 div columns: fixed and liquid. Fixed one must be removable. Liquid one must be the first in code

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Consider the following 2 cols html structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left">some text</div>
    <div class="right">some text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
.left { float: left; width: 200px; background: red; }
.right { overflow: hidden; background: green; }
```

The same code in jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vny2H/

So we have 2 columns. The left column width is fixed, the width of the right one is liquid.
If we remove the left column from html, the right column stretches to 100% of parent #container width.

The question is: can we change the order of the left and right columns?
(I need it for SEO)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

---

### Added

There's one interesting method to reach what I want, but fixed column becomes not removable. The method is based on negative margin. http://jsfiddle.net/YsZNG/

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="mainCol">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div><!-- .inner end -->
    </div><!-- .mainCol end -->

    <div id="sideCol">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div><!-- .sideCol end -->

</div><!-- #container end -->
```

CSS

```
#container { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; }

#mainCol { float: right; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 -200px; }
#mainCol .inner { margin: 0 0 0 200px; background: #F63; }

#sideCol { float: left; width: 200px; background: #FCF; }
```

So we have 2 ways:

1. Using "float" for the fixed column and "overflow: hidden" for the liquid. Fixed column becomes removable. But liquid one goes second in code.
2. Using negative margin. Liquid column goes first in code. But fixed one is not removable.

Is there a third way, when fixed column is removable and liquid one is the first in code?

---

### Added

Half-decision has been suggested by @lnrbob. The main idea - using table-like divs. http://jsfiddle.net/UmbBF/1/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="right">some text</div>
    <div class="left">some text</div>
</div>
```

СSS

```
#container { display: table; width: 100%; }
.right { display: table-cell; background: green; }
.left { display: table-cell;  width: 200px; background: red; }
```

This method is suitable, when a fixed column is placed to the right in a site. But if we need it to the left - it seems to be impossible to do this.

Comment: i man not sure if this is what you need but this is new and wont work on legacy browsers. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: This is a fantastic thing, but it seems to be a modification of just one block. So it doesn't suit for a site column structure.

Comment: well after all a 'site column structure' would itself be inside a div or body. i believe it is specifically made for site structure. and it will be better baked into the browser hence will be more reliable :) it is alot easier than managing floating divs and all :D i use it and it took me about 5 minutes to understand and implement it

Comment: Ok, but I don't see any example, how to form multicolumns, when there are several div blocks in each of the column. Could you write such example, please?

Comment: i dont see the complication.. :O write simply as you would, treating a column as a separate div :) as you said it is just floating divs for structure done right. treat single columns as a seprate div and you should be good

Comment: but again, this will *not* work in legacy browsers like ie 6,7,8,9 or maybe even FF 3.* but not sure for FF

Comment: There is *no pure HTML/CSS solution* that matches *all* of your requirements. Forget about trying to reorder the HTML and keep it as it is. Any SEO gain from changing the order will be negligible.

Comment: I think this is not the most important thing about SEO :)

Comment: @thirtydot - I think I've just provided a solution that solves all requirements actually, although I must be honest, I didn't think it was possible either on initial inspection. Good question Webars. I've favourited this as I actually think this scenario has some real value for further use... Nice one!

Comment: @BizNuge: I said "pure HTML/CSS solution", which your answer isn't (due to the code needed to change the class). But besides that technicality, it's good enough, and probably the best he's going to get. You can have an upvote, but I'm still sure that the correct solution is to simply not swap the `div`s, as per @roryf's answer. Rather than this question, @Webars should instead be asking on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) what difference (if any) this will make for the search engines he's concerned with. I suspect the answer will be "virtually no difference".

Comment: @thirtydot - No, I mean the second answer I provided. I felt it was sufficiently different to warrant a second answer. http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/aAE3q/12/ and this one is pure CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think that this is a rather pointless endeavour, because the only reason to try is for dubious SEO benefits. But, I've been dragged back to this question so many times that I'm going to bring something to the table.

If I was forced on pain of death to come up with a pure CSS solution, this is it - but I don't recommend it:

http://jsfiddle.net/RbWgr/

The magic is `transform: scaleX(-1);`. That's applied to `.container` to flip the visual order, and then also to the child `div`s so that *the content* of each `div` is not flipped.

- It won't work in IE7, because I'm using `display: table-cell`.
- It's not so hot in IE8 - any text looks horrible, as is usual with `filter`s. But, it does work.
- Extra `div` wrappers were required to make it work in Opera - and the text doesn't look perfect.

It works fantastically in other modern browsers (IE9, Chrome, Safari, Firefox), but applying `transform`s to a parent of "every element" might have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Fantastic! The best answer I've seen. But how did you know, that negative value flips cells? And second, it seems to me, that nested divs are required for all browsers, not only for opera. Am I right?

Comment: I "just knew" that negative values do that. It's like Photoshop - if when transforming something you set it to have a width of `-100%`, it's flipped. The nested `div`s *are* required only for Opera - this is a version without the nested `div`s, and it's broken in Opera but it works everywhere else the original one does: http://jsfiddle.net/RbWgr/1/. Without looking too deeply, it appears that Opera can't apply `transform`s to table cells.

Comment: Yes, now I see. My respect for answer!

Answer (score 6):

Consider the semantics of the content you are marking up before anything else, that will almost always lead to a solution that has both decent markup and is search engine friendly.

For instance, is `.right` the main content of the page, and `.left` some supplementary information or navigation? In that case, mark it up as such and the search engines will do a good job of interpreting it the way you want them to. HTML5 provides many elements for just this purpose:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">etc.</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
        <h1>My nice, juicy content</h1>
        <p>Cool stuff, huh?!</p>
    <article>
</div>
```

Or for supplementary content you might consider `<aside>` or simply `<div role="supplementary">`.

Google will happily scrape that and recognise the difference between the navigation and the actual content, the idea that source order is important no longer applies to SEO in the same way it did a few years ago.

Comment: +1 For hitting the nail. No SEO stress, just write good content.

Comment: Yes, you're right: .right is the main content of the page, and .left is navigation. I have no doubt, that Google rightly understands semantically well-formed site. But besides Google there're a lot of other search engines. And my SEO experience tells me, that the higher main content on a page the higher site's place in search results. Also if a site is young and a page is large, search bot can simply go away before it indexes whole content. But the real question - is it impossible to make such structure that meets my requirements?

Answer (score 3):

Because your elements have same height you can do this:

```
#container { overflow: hidden; position:relative; }
.left { float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: red; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
.right { overflow: hidden; height: 200px; background: green; margin-left:200px;}
```

Fiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/Ptm3R/9/

Comment: Using "position: absolute" in a site column structure is a bad idea. First of all, imagine a situation, when right column height is smaller than left column height. Left column will be cut by footer or window. And secondly, in your variant, when we remove the left column from html - we see an empty space on place, where the left column was, but instead the right column must stretch to 100% of parent #container width. But thanks in any case for your answer. Take +1 for it. :)

Comment: if you didn't have "height" I wouldn't suggest position:absolute ;)

Comment: Excuse me for this confusion :) It was just for visualization as they have no content.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I'm not sure why you're boiling it down to having to use only two id's ( [#left / #right] OR [**#mainCol** / **#sideCol**] )...

Would it not be far easier to use the mainCol/sideCol solution you had in JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/YsZNG/ and introduce a third class that could be applied to the main div in the absence of the sideCol programmatically.

As in http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/aAE3q/4/

Sorry. I may well have missed the point of all this, but I've had previous gut wrenching agony with trying to work in fluid/fixed mixture sites so just thought I'd share my own feelings on the matter...

**UPDATE**

I provided a second answer to this now that I think works. Sorry to double answer but it seemed sufficiently different from my initial response that I thought it would stand on its own two feet.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to the question. I know, this is the simplest way. And even .inner can be removed in your example to make code even more clear. But I'd want to know, if there's some css-guru, that solved this problem only with css.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your browser support requirements. For IE8 and above (and all modern browsers) you could use `display:` to set a table layout (still using your `<div />`'s of course.)

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/UmbBF/1/)  -I've only added javascript so you can toggle whether the element is hidden or not easily :)

Comment: Incredible! It's a pity, that IE7 is still supported on most websites. Though, if a client is not very meticulous, it can be fixed with JS. :) And I have a question about your code. Isn't a div with "display: table-row" required?

Comment: I don't think a table-row is strictly required - remember this is purely visual, if it looks right cross browser, you're good! I seem to remember safari might prefer a table-row display but Chrome was fine for me. Just test it :)

Comment: This method is suitable, when a fixed column is placed to the right in a site. But if we need it to the left - it seems to be impossible to do this. :(

Comment: oh I get it, well confusing. So you want `<div class="right" />` to appear on the right but actually be first in the dom?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I have understood the question now I think. Can you advise how you are removing the left column? This might be an easier way to tackle it

Comment: The left column is just a block in admin panel. So I can switch it on or off for different pages. And when I switch the left column off, I want the main content to fill the whole site width.

Comment: @Webars let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1282/discussion-between-lnrbob-and-webars)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/aAE3q/12/</strike>

<strike>this seems to satisfy the brief I think. Works in FF anyway, but I'm unsure how other browsers might react to the table type display attributes.</strike>

<strike>**UPDATE**</strike>

<strike>Have tested this in FireFox(4), IE(9), Opera(11), Safari(5)[Win] and Chrome(12) and the layout seems to be robust across all browsers.</strike>

<strike>Rather surprising really...</strike>

**UPDATE FOLLOWING CLARIFICATION**

*thanks to @thirtydot for that*

**http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/aAE3q/19/**

Works ONLY in Firefox 4 as far as I can tell, after some brief checking... But it's a start...

Comment: This is identical to @lnrbob's answer (look closely at the version of @lnrbob's answer that has been edited into the question, particularly how the HTML doesn't match the demo), with the exact same problems. Here's a version of the demo in your answer with some extra `<p>` to enlighten you: http://jsfiddle.net/aAE3q/13/

Comment: @thirtydot - see what you mean about the left/right thing... I seem to have overlooked that the elements were the wrong way round... hmmmmmm...

Comment: just a minute... http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/aAE3q/16/ even if I add another element into the columnic layout, their position in markup directly correlates to their position in the render. This is what Webars was asking for wasn't it?

Comment: He wants the HTML to be `RIGHT LEFT`, but the visual display to be `LEFT RIGHT`. Take his original demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vny2H/31/ and try to make it function and look *exactly the same* (you can remove LEFT in that demo), but have RIGHT first *in the HTML*. That is the task, and I'm 99% sure it's impossible with "pure CSS" (unless there's some funky and not widely supported CSS3 method that can help).

Comment: @thirtydot - ummm... so you're saying he wants the left div to show "visually" in the render on the left hand side no matter what the positioning of the elements within the markup? is this the scenario?

Comment: @Webars - Yeah. shame about the FF only solution with this, but there you go. I agree with thirtydot about this being something that is probably not do-able across all browsers to be honest. Probably the best way to do it would be either introducing a class to one of the divs serverside (as per my previous suggestion I think) or by perhaps manipulating the DOM via Javascript to position the elements in the order you need once the page is loaded... Quite an interesting question once I figured out what you meant fully. ;)

Comment: I'm already thinking about this question over a year from time to time. :) Cause I have a companion, which works mainly in photoshop, but also knows css in general. His ideas about sites are often crazy and impossible to realize. But because of it I'm permanently improving myself as css-designer. :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure about the SEO value too much with this. Your point about googlebots getting bored of page length and moving on makes some sense I suppose. Don't know enough about bots/spidering to make any assumptions really.

Comment: @BizNuge: `caption-side:left;` is an interesting attempt. That never crossed my mind. As it why it only works in Firefox, [see here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/caption-side): "CSS2 also defined the values left and right for this property, but they were removed in CSS2.1 (although they are still supported in Gecko (Firefox)).". [Then again](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-tables-algorithms/Overview.src.htm), `left`/`right` might be supported again in the future: "[In CSS 2.1] the only possible values are top, bottom and inherit. CSS 3 will also add left and right.".

Comment: @thirtydot - I actually sat for a while with the w3 display attribute listing (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) open just thinking about what the hell might even slightly work... Sort of strange that it was removed from the spec, since it seems like it might have been of some use (albeit in this very specific circumstance). ho hum!

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the left col inside the right one at the bottom?

http://jsfiddle.net/vny2H/32/

Comment: Interesting idea. But: 1) It doesn't work in IE7. 2) On practice, there will be blocks in most cases, not alone text. And you can see, what happens, if we put a block in .rightCol :) http://jsfiddle.net/fHg5t/ Thank you anyway.