# floating menu position - fixed to the left side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have [this template](http://www.turie.eu/floatingmenu) and it works fine, but I need to fix that floating menu to the left side of page (not to the left side of browser window). I need to have it stitched when I change resolution or reduce browser window.

I have one idea with two columns with float: left, but there must be a better solution.

Thank you.

Comment: without 2 columns it will always float over the text

Comment: Very bad layout. You need a new one. Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483603/2-div-columns-fixed-and-liquid-fixed-one-must-be-removable-liquid-one-must-be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
#content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 230px;  //change from auto to a set margin 
}

#floatMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 200px;   //REMOVE this margin altogether
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You do understand that this will un-center the content and mess the layout up?

Comment: @Zanfa.  not if the OP also changes the `#content div`'s `margin` from `auto` to the above listed `230px`.  That's why it needed to change. check it in your console window.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to move the #floatmenu div inside the #content div. Also you need to manually change the margin-left in the floatingmenu css file to -220px etc. And in addition you would need to change the position attribute on #content div to relative, to make sure the absolutely positioned menu is positioned relative to the #content div's left side.

All in all, drop the floating menu, using JS to add annoying widgets to your website is so 90s. And, well, annoying.

Comment: Probably two columns will be the best solution. Why do you think it's annoying? I plan to fill it with social icons and it's always better to place them as near as possible to content which user like. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: @culter Worry about the floating social icons after, I repeat, AFTER, you have content. Believe me, if you have ingenious content, not having social icons will not stop it from being shared. Not having great content will. Having those buttons is not some magical solution that automatically makes your site popular. Instead, dump the icons, have a cleaner, nicer design and focus on what makes your site appealing to users (again, the buttons are not the correct answer, content is).

Comment: You're right, Zanfa. But I think, in case you have unique and good content, it's a mistake not to use social networks since the beginning. I know there is million of web-content creators that think their content is best and therefore people have intention to be sceptic, but I'm not one of them. :)