# CSS columns: both fluid and flexible in width

Tags: javascript, html, css, fluid-layout

The challenge is to come up with this:

```
+--------------------------------------++----------------+
| This is a header with potentially    || button div     |
|                                      ||                |
| long text that will wrap most likely |+----------------+
|                                      |
| but can't go under the button to the |
|                                      |
| right                                |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Not a big deal with a typical 2 column layout where you set the left column's margin to equal that of the div on the right. The variable in this particular example, however, is that I won't know how wide the div on the right will be at any given time (it's based on a line of text that will vary.

In summary, I need:

- a 2 column layout
- both columns take up the full width
- column on right is as wide as the text it contains
- column on left is as wide as the leftover space

It seems like I would have had to have built this before but I'm stumped.

I'm open to CSS, JS or jQuery solutions.

Actually, I can already see a fairly easy jQuery solution. I can grab the rendered width of the div on the right, then do some math subtracting that width from the width of the parent container and then setting the width of the left column the same. That'll be my fallback plan if there's not a clean CSS option.

Comment: Do the columns have to be equal height? Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Nope...no need for equal height. Browser support...for now, let's just say webkit (valid browsers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/vpADP/

It will work in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="buttonDiv">button div as wide as text</div>
<div id="leftDiv">
    left div
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#leftDiv {
    overflow: hidden
}
#buttonDiv {
    float: right
}
```

That's not the typical use of `overflow: hidden`, [read this for details](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

Comment: Brilliant! I had no idea about that technique. That's great. Only nit-pick is that it reverses the content flow in the markup, but that's a side effect I can happily live with in this particular instance.

Comment: Yeah, that is a downside. It's not possible with this technique to fix that. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483603/2-div-columns-fixed-and-liquid-fixed-one-must-be-removable-liquid-one-must-be) is the kind of crazy that ensues when you try :)

Comment: I need to do this too but with the requirements reversed (left column takes precedence, with right column getting the scraps). I tried messing with the fiddle, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @RTF: Looking at [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665839/scrollbar-not-appearing-in-2-column-fluid-width-layout), do you want this? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/PJdNW/3/

Comment: @thirtydot Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. I had actually just gone the JS route, which works fine, but this is definitely preferable. If you want to throw that into an answer on my question, I'll accept it for you. Otherwise, I'll answer it myself with your code.

Comment: @thirtydot: On second though, that's not really what I was looking for. The first time I looked at it, I didn't notice that you'd fixed the height in pixels on the scrollable content area. I was hoping for a solution whereby CSS would figure it out, so I'll stick with my JS solution for now.