# Scrollbar not appearing in 2-column fluid width layout

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I'm using a 2-column div layout where the widths of both the left and right columns is non-deterministic. The left column div holds an image. The right column div holds a header div and a text content div below it. The width of the left column image takes precedence over the right column, and the right column gets the scraps in terms of width. Both of these columns are inside a div container, which has a fixed height (and width, but that doesn't matter). This layout is working using the following code:

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollable-content-header {
    font-size: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.scrollable-content {
    font-size: 18px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The text content div should be scrollable if it overflows the container height. But I can't get the scrollbar to appear on the `.scrollable-content` element. Here's some HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="left">
        <img id="image" src="http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/image/css-icon.png"/>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="scrollable-content-header">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="scrollable-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur... etc.
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

If the `container` element has `overflow: auto` instead of hidden, then a scrollbar will appear. But it will allow scrolling of the entire container. I don't want that, only the `.scrollable-content` should be scrollable, not including the header. I'm assuming that the `overflow: hidden` trick on the right column div in order to achieve the fluid width effect is causing problems.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJdNW/
Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
From what I understand, CSS cannot figure out what the height of the scrollable-content needs to be, so in order for the scrollbar to work and be the correct height, the pixel height of the scrollable-content needs to be set.

In my case, the height of the overall container is dynamic, so I opted for a JS solution, which gets the height of the overall container and subtracts the height of the scrollable-content header in order to get the pixel value I need for the scrollable-content (plus some fine-tuning i.e. margins).

I'll leave this question open for the moment in the hopes that I'm wrong and CSS is up to the task.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height of your container, otherwise the container will automatically resize to the content length.  Also, set the overflow attribute to scroll.  Fix below:

```
        .container {
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .left {
            float: left;
        }
        .right {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .scrollable-content-header {
            font-size: 25px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        .scrollable-content {
            font-size: 18px;
            overflow: scroll;
            height:200px;
        }
```

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/PJdNW/1/

Comment: But that's cutting off the content at the bottom of the scrollable container. Also, setting the overflow attr to scroll will permanently leave the scrollbar there regardless of whether the content is large enough to be scrolled. I'm not really happy about that.

Comment: you could set it dynamically based on the content length.  i'll update the fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/PJdNW/2/   I think something like this is what you're trying to accomplish, if I understand you correctly.  Let me know if this helps you.  I've done a lot of styles similar to this so I'm sure I can help you come up with the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I was really hoping that CSS would be able to just "figure out" how high the scrollable-content container is. The problem with hard coding the height is that it's dependent on the height of the header above it, and the container height, which might change (I forgot to mention that). It the font size changes, the height needs to be recalculated. What's worse is that I'm providing controls to increase and decrease the font size on the page. I know it's not impossible, I could do it easily enough with a bit of JS. It's just so unfortunate, I would've thought that CSS could handle this.

Comment: Incidentally, I had previously tried another approach to achieve the same layout. I used a table with 2 rows with The left column image spanning both of them. The 2nd row contained the scrollable-content div, and everything was working perfectly, exactly how I wanted. Except for one thing. Some phantom padding at the bottom of the td cell containing the scrollable-content-header. I just couldn't explain or get rid of it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Yeah, unfortunately css is still a little limited.  The only thing that I can think of is using js to adjust the height of the container.  Another thought was to maybe 'overlay' your images on top of the parent container and set the margins of your content, but i think it may still cause a problem when the image size is adjusted.  I don't think you're going to be able to get a full css solution without using js for some calculation on this.  Well... maybe... let me play with this a little bit more.

Comment: Ok, that option didn't work either in pure css... you'll have to use js for this.  Do you need any help on the js?

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate alright. No thanks, I'll be alright with the JS. For what it's worth, here it is working (sort of) with the table solution I mentioned. As you can see though, there's some spacing that I can't explain, and changing image sizes causes problems too: http://jsfiddle.net/f2rLN/